# Using expects().twice.with().returns using Mocha, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, mocha.js

I am using mocha to mock my tests.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do.

```
ClassName.expects(:method_name).twice.with() do |options|
  options == input_options1 || options == input_options2
end.returns("abc123", "def456")
```

The above works.

But is there another way, where I can specify two different types on input_options, something like,

```
ClassName.expects(:method_name).twice.with(input_options1,input_options2).returns("abc123", "def456")
```

where my function "method_name" accepts only one parameter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, there isn't. You have to accommodate with the first solution you proposed.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
ClassName.expects(:method_name).with(input_options1).returns("abc123")
ClassName.expects(:method_name).with(input_options2).returns("def456")
```

Comment: I liked this solution cause it gives you a control of the output based on the input

Answer (score 1):

Try Following.

```
ClassName.expects(:method_name).twice.with(any_parameters).returns("abc123", "def456")
```